# Filesystem Information shows between Plymouth and Login Screen 16.04

Tags: boot, filesystem, 16.04, plymouth, tty

This is by no means a major issue but I thought it was a bit odd. Immediately after the Plymouth splash screen disappears and before the usual Ubuntu login screen appears, a tty style terminal displaying some kind of information about the filesystem appears.

This appears to be a filesystem independent issue as it occurred on my system with both a btrfs and ext4 root partition. And the output during the terminal flash appears to be something to do with first accessing the filesystem. It also occurs as I shutdown or restart the laptop, and appears to show information about unmounting the root filesystem.

This issue seems to only be with 16.04, I didn't have this issue with 14.04. I have only ever done clean installs of 16.04, no upgrades from 14.04. I didn't change anything about how I installed 16.04 as opposed to 14.04.

Not sure if this information is pertinent but:

- My system uses an SSD as the only storage media
- My system has a UEFI bios and boots from an EFI partition

I'm just curious as to why this output to the terminal during the boot process is visible while all the rest aren't, and if anyone knows a way to correct this.

Answer (score 1):

If the message is something like

```
/dev/sda2: clean, 201776/60878736 files, 4991277/243040256 blocks
```

You need to do ... nothing, thats perfectly fine, this message should normaly be invisible but somehow it snuck to visbility.

It just tells you that there are no orphaned nodes and that your journal is clean.

Comment: Yes that's the message but my question is why is this happening. I probably should have made that more clear, my bad!

Comment: Not clear why its happening but its happening to mostly all of us who run 16.04 right now

Comment: They didn't add much and they didn't polish much either. What exactly did they do? Just change the name? Haha